# Counting Number of Incidences from Range 1 that Exist in Range 2

Tags: excel, vba

Forgive me for being new to VBA. I have been working on this for too long now and need help.

- (J:N) is my dictionary.
- (G) is inbound callers

I want to Count the number of Inbound Callers by Each Timezone.

[image: Total Number of Calls from Each Time Zone]

[image: Phone Calls and Dictionary]

Comment: you can use Formulas, or pivot table. Don't need to use VBA for this.

Comment: @MAKAH I need to use VBA for this as it is a small component of a process I am automating.

Comment: @Makah (not sure if the above tagged or alerted you)